# Joining (merge, union) non-overlapping vector polygons with QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, clip, union

I look for a solution how I can join several polygons that do not overlap with each other and have no common sides, by creating a new polygon. That is, it should be an output polygon  covering the "outer" vertices of several input polygons, but in general repeating their shape (see attached figure, red line).
I tried several features in QGIS, in particular Convex Hull and Minimum bounding geometry, but it didn't work out what I needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a multipolygon layer and create your multipolygons from your polygons based on an attribute value, proximity or something else... On these multipolygon features you can then apply the function of your choice: bounding box, oriented bounding box, convex hull and it will "merge like" your original features.  Below is an example, the 2 top features are part of the same multipolygon. First picture before and second picture after a convex hull operation. Tested on QGIS.

[image: Before the convex]

[image: After the convex hull]

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but a starting point - maybe someone can further develop the main idea. The basic idea is to connect the centroids of neighboring polygons with a line and than buffer that line. It works if the polygons have an attribute (`id` in my case) in the order the polygons should be connected. But that is easy to generate.

You can than use the following expression to create a visualization with geometry generator or actual geometries with `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geometry by expression`:

```
buffer (
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (
                1,  
                count( $id)-1
            ),
            make_line ( 
                centroid ( 
                    geometry ( 
                        get_feature_by_id (
                            @layer, 
                            @element
                        )
                    )
                ),
                centroid ( 
                    geometry ( 
                        get_feature_by_id (
                            @layer, 
                            @element+1
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ), 0.19
)
```

*Red: original polygons, blue: dynamically created gemoetries using geometry generator with the expression from above:*
[image]

Comment: This buffer approach is really promising! However, in my QGIS, the code only fires for the temporary layer via symbology (after reprojecting to the projected coordinate system). In the toolbox, the code does not work (an expression error is displayed for static shapefile, or eval error "Cannot use aggregate function in this context" for temporary), but it may be a bug. I will have to sort this out...

Comment: Your question was closed as not enough focused. That's why I edited it, hoping it gets re-opened so that other answers can be added. An even more promising approach seems to connect the vertices of each polygon with the vertices of the next polygon (same order ad the lines in the answer above). In any case an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got almost an "ideal" result for my polygons to what I expected - it was the Concave Hull QGIS function, also available in PosGIS and other systems. It worked well for other similar polygons as well.